# How to stop rendering a vue carousel component after all it's data is shown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As title says, I want to stop rendering a vue carousel component after it's data is shown or after x seconds. I haven't found any related information about this. I know it's quite... weird to do this, but still I want to know how to, for some projects. Here's the code:

```
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col latest-news max-width">
              <carousel
                :per-page="1"
        :mouse-drag="false"
        :autoplay="true"
        :paginationEnabled="false"
        :loop="true"
        :speed="1500"
        :autoplayTimeout="7000"
      >
        <slide v-for="post in posts_1" :post="post" :key="post.id">
          <NewsTitle class="most-important" :post="post" :key="post.id" />
        </slide>
      </carousel>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop rendering"?

Comment: What I meant is to hide it after X seconds passed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what do you need?

```
<template>
    <carousel
        v-if="showCarousel"
        ...
    >
        ...
    </carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            showCarousel: true,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        hideCarousel: function(){
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.showCarousel = false;
            }, 5000);
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.hideCarousel();
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to hide your carousel you should be dependent on `showCarousel` variable. Also you need to add condition `v-if="showCarousel"` to your `carousel` tag. My code should hide carousel after 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds.

Comment: @Dan, ok, I changed to arrow function.

Comment: I'm getting some parsing errors after the components section, line 124 here: https://codepen.io/daniel-alvarez/pen/JjbWbNa

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, you have missed opening `<template>` tag at the beginning.

Comment: @webprogrammerr check again, please. I attached the whole code: https://codepen.io/daniel-alvarez/pen/JjbWbNa

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, you have wrong syntax in your code. `getPosts: async function() {` should be in `methods`. Also check your `components` property. It is included after closing brace `};`.

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, I suppose, you need to separate your html, css and js on codepen.

Comment: @webprogrammerr, I've corrected the syntax, but now the carousel doesn't appear at all.

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, Can you show me the code? Can you update codepen?

Comment: @webprogrm, No errors, the banner is just gone. updated: https://codepen.io/daniel-alvarez/pen/JjbWbNa

Comment: @DanielAlvarez , do you use vue2? Put your `getPosts` and `getFeaturedImages` inside `methods` property.

Comment: @webprogrm, Done, still not displayed. Yes, I'm using vue2

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, can you update codepen again?

Comment: Done. https://codepen.io/daniel-alvarez/pen/JjbWbNa

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, but I still see `getPosts: async function() {...}` and `getFeaturedImages: function(posts) {...}` outside of `methods: {}`.

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, can you show me your previous version of code with working carousel?

Comment: @webprogrm, I've sent them correctly now, still not working. This is a previous working version: https://codepen.io/daniel-alvarez/pen/ZEBeLXw

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, in your working code mentioned methods are in the correct place. Can you show me the latest version? Should be some errors.

Comment: @webprrm, this is the latest: https://codepen.io/daniel-alvarez/pen/bGBqgMv

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, it looks fine now.

Comment: @DanielAlvarez, can you create `div` wrapper for `carousel` component and put `v-if="showCarousel"` to there? I mean: `<div v-if="showCarousel"><carousel ...></carousel></div>`

Comment: @webprogm, I've seen something interesting... now it works, but I had to set the time to 55000 ms, (seems the site is taking some time to load and the vue component starts counting since the reload, not the component display.) I think I can handle it with this, thank you very much.